# How to stack icon moon from font-awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I didn't find how to stack icon moon from FA :

```
<span class="fa-stack">
 <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-moon fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> sleep
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/myYUh/90/

Icon is hidden, we only see the square :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first is a typo: Font Awesome has no `fa-moon` icon, however it does have a `fa-moon-o` icon:

[image: fa-moon-o]

Once you've fixed that, the next problem is that the `fa-inverse` class gives your `fa-moon-o` icon a colour of `#fff` (white), which makes it invisible on top of the white page background which you see through the `fa-square-o` icon.

Unless your own page has a background which isn't white, to fix this, either remove the `fa-inverse` class:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
 <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span> sleep
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/myYUh/91/).

Or change `fa-square-o` to `fa-square`:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
 <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> sleep
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/myYUh/92/).